# Angular UI-Router use template based on passed value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state in my Angular 1.3 app:

```
    .state('department.filetransfer', {
    url: '/filetransfer/:deptID',
    templateUrl: function($stateParams, $log) {
        return 'modules/department/templates/department.filetransfer.'+$stateParams.deptID+'.html';
    },
    controller: 'DeptFiletransferCtrl as ftc',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'filetransfer',
        access: 'public'
    }
});
```

And then in my application I have a link such as

`ui-sref="department.filetransfer.accounting"`

But I get a console error

`Error: Could not resolve 'department.filetransfer.accounting' from state 'department'`

What did I miss?

Comment: But Steve, you do not have state *'department.filetransfer.accounting'* you have only **'department.filetransfer'**. So it is, I'd say, clear message you are getting - such state does not exist. And `ui-sref="..."` must contain the name of existing state

Comment: I might be doing it wrong, but what I want to do is have a state "filetransfer" and then use a different template URL for this state depending on department ID, so "accounting.html", "hr.html", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kny2Zlx2AofHO3vDuOgi?p=preview)

The way how to pass `param` is via an *object* `{paramName1:value1, paramName2: value2}`:

```
ui-sref="department.filetransfer({deptID:accounting})"
```

The above example is suitable when **`accounting`** as a variable in `$scope`.

In case, that we need to pass string value, we should do it like this:

```
ui-sref="department.filetransfer({deptID:'accounting'})"
```

As documented here

#### [`ui-sref`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)

> A directive that binds a link (`<a>` tag) to a state. If the state has an associated URL, the directive will automatically generate & update the href attribute via the `$state.href()` method. Clicking the link will trigger a state transition with optional parameters.
>
> Also middle-clicking, right-clicking, and ctrl-clicking on the link will be handled natively by the browser.
>
> You can also use relative state paths within ui-sref, just like the relative paths passed to `$state.go()`. You just need to be aware that the path is relative to the state that the link lives in, in other words the state that loaded the template containing the link.
>
> You can specify options to pass to `$state.go()` using the **`ui-sref-opts`** attribute. Options are restricted to `location`, `inherit`, and `reload`.

Comment: Close, but now I get a 404: `GET http://localhost:3001/modules/departments/templates/department.filetransfer..html 404 (Not Found)` noting the 2 dots, the carrierID did not get passed.

Comment: Could you please check what is generated inside of your `templateUrl`? what is the link for template?

Comment: Well, it seems that there is just doubled `..`? won't you agree? I mean the `filetransfer..htm‌​l`, maybe the parameter is containing trailing dot... I am trying to say, just observe (with debuger or console) what was passed, and be sure that the template url is constructed well... you are really very close now ;)

Comment: Should've been `modules/departments/templates/department.filetransfer.accounting.htm‌​l`

Comment: I see, but now we are almost there... just the parameter passed, or constructed string adds the dot.. that should be easy to fix.. will try to show in an example... meanwhile, you can try this: ui-sref="department.filetransfer({deptID:'accounting'})" where param is a string not extern param

Comment: Great to see that - there is an working example http://plnkr.co/edit/Kny2Zlx2AofHO3vDuOgi?p=preview Good luck with UI-Router